# Best Seller Block (links not working) - Magento 2.2

Tags: redirect, magento2.2.3, link, redirect-url

Here i need to solve some issue where,

1. When i click on the product image **(BLUE CIRCLE)**, in the Best seller block, we are redirected towards the Home Page
2. Similarly, when the name of the product is clicked **(RED CIRCLE)**, some other page is opened.

*I think if someone could help me in changing the link of the pages that are being redirected, would solve the issue.*

*I want the product page to get opened, wheather we click on the product image OR we click on the name of the product.*

THANKYOU IN Advance

[image: Best Seller Block]
    create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$storeId = $storeManager->getStore()->getId();
 $collection = $productCollectionFactory->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft( 
                            'sales_order_item', 
                            'e.entity_id = sales_order_item.product_id', 
                            array('qty_ordered'=>'SUM(sales_order_item.qty_ordered)')) 
                            ->group('e.entity_id')->limit(8);
    $imageHelper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
    $_helper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
    $priceHelper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data');
?>

products-">
            
            
                
                
                    ";
                       // print_r($_product->getData());
                        $product_data = $_product->getData();
                           //echo "

```
";
                    // print_r($product_data);
                        //  echo  $product_title = $product_data['meta_title'];
                          // $product_title_url = str_replace(' ','-',$product_title);
        //                  $product_title_url = strtolower($product_title_url).'.html';
                    ///exit;
                    ?>
                    ' : '' ?>
                        
                    getId();?>" data-container="product-grid">
                        
                        getProductUrl() ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo" tabindex="-1">
                            
                                
                                    init($_product, 'product_page_image_large')
                                                ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
                                                ->keepFrame(FALSE)
                                                ->resize(285, 285)
                                                ->getUrl();
                                    ?>
                                    " />
                                
                            
                        
                        
                        
                               
                                
                                    getName(); ?>   
                                
                            
                        
                          getId(); ?>">
                                
                                    getId(); ?>-widget-product-grid" data-price-amount="getPrice(); ?>" data-price-type="finalPrice" class="price-wrapper ">
                                        currency($_product->getPrice(), true, false); ?>
                                    
                                
                            

                                


                                             
                                        isSaleable()): ?>
                                            create('Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart');
                                                $formKey = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey'); 
                                                $wishlistHelper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data');
                                                $wishlistUrl = $wishlistHelper->getAddParams($_product);    

                                            ?>
                                            getAddUrl($_product); ?>" method="post">
                                                getId(); ?>" />
                                                getFormKey();?>">
                                                "
                                                        class="action tocart primary">
                                                    
                                                
                                            
                                        
                                            getIsSalable()): ?>
                                                
                                            
                                                
                                            
                                        

                                        

                                   create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
                                    // $customerSession->setMyValue('test');
                                    $wishlistHelper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data');
                                                    $wishlistUrl = $wishlistHelper->getAddParams($_product);
                                   ?>

                                    isLoggedIn() == false){  ?> onclick="social_popup('popup')" ">
                                        isLoggedIn() == false){  ?>
                                          isLoggedIn() == true){
                                                     ?> 
                                               role="button" title=""
                                               aria-label=""

                                               data-post=''
                                                 >
                                                
                                                
                                                
                                            


                                         "
                                               aria-label=""

                                               data-post=''
                                               >
                                              
                                              
                                                
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                    

                                

                    
                    
                

                <?php echo($iterator == count($collection) + 1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>





$(document).ready(function(){  
   $("#flexiselDemo1s").flexisel({
        visibleItems:4,
        animationSpeed: 1000,
        itemsToScroll: 1,
        autoPlaySpeed: 3000,
        infinite: true,
        navigationTargetSelector: null,
        autoPlay: {
            enable: false,
            interval: 5000,
            pauseOnHover: true
        },      
        enableResponsiveBreakpoints: true,
        responsiveBreakpoints: { 
            portrait: { 
                changePoint:480,
                visibleItems: 1
            }, 
            landscape: { 
                changePoint:642,
                visibleItems: 2
            },
            tablet: { 
                changePoint:769,
                visibleItems: 3
            }
        }
    });

    });

    

<?php
```

// $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of object manager
// $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
// $connection = $resource->getConnection();

// //Select Data from table
// $sql = "SELECT `t2`.`value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` `t1` LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` `t2` ON `t1`.`entity_id` = `t2`.`entity_id` WHERE `t2`.`attribute_id` = '166' AND `t1`.`value` = '247'";
// $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql); // gives associated array, table fields as key in array.
// echo '<>';
// print_r($result);
    ?>

Comment: Please share you phtml code of best seller block.
Thanks

Comment: Where do i find the phtml code of the best seller block ?

Comment: I found the solution, By changing the visibility in the product details page in the backend, i changed the visibility to Catalog, Search. Now the link is working. 

But now the problem is that the links are different for both the product image & the product name. 

Please help 
Thanks